# Annoying persistent error with Python : Beginner

Tags: python

I'm just starting to learn python and keep getting an error that I just can't figure out.  Any help would be massively appreciated.  Basically, I keep getting the following error:

```
Enter an int: 8

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Documents\Python Stuff\Find Prime Factors of Number.py", line 16, in <module>
    once_cycle()
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Documents\Python Stuff\Find Prime Factors of Number.py", line 8, in once_cycle
    while x==0:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

I see lots of people are having the same problem, but when I look at what people have told them to do I can't figure it out.  Anyway, my code is this.  I've re-checked all my indentation and can't see a problem with it.  The aim of this program is to find the prime factors of an int (although it's only 90% complete).  It's written in Python 2.7.3.

```
import math
testedInt = float(raw_input("Enter an int: "))
workingInt = testedInt
x = 0

def once_cycle():
    for dividor in range(1, int(math.floor(math.sqrt(testedInt))+1)):
        while x==0:
            print "Called"
            if (workingInt%dividor == 0):
                workingInt = workingInt/dividor
                x = 1
    if (workingInt > 1):
        once_cycle()
    return

once_cycle()

print workingInt
```

Thanks in advance for any help,

Sam

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `one_cycle()` function you are *at some point* assigning to `x`:

```
        if (workingInt%dividor == 0):
            workingInt = workingInt/dividor
            x = 1
```

This makes `x` a local variable. You are also referring to it with a test:

```
    while x==0:
```

but before it is assigned *to*. This is the cause of your exception.

Either add `x = 0` at the start of your function, or declare it a global (if that is what you meant it to be). By the looks of it, you don't use `x` outside of the function, so you probably didn't mean it to be.

The following works; `workingInt` is also being modified so it needs to be declared `global`:

```
def once_cycle():
    global workingInt
    x = 0

    for dividor in range(1, int(math.floor(math.sqrt(testedInt))+1)):
        while x==0:
            print "Called"
            if (workingInt%dividor == 0):
                workingInt = workingInt/dividor
                x = 1
    if (workingInt > 1):
        once_cycle()
    return
```

or, simplified:

```
def once_cycle():
    global workingInt

    for dividor in range(1, int(math.sqrt(testedInt)) + 1):
        while True:
            if workingInt % dividor == 0:
                workingInt = workingInt / dividor
                break
    if workingInt > 1:
        once_cycle()
```

`int(floating_point_number)` already takes the floor of a floating point argument.

Note that you end up with an infinite loop if `workingInt % dividor` is *not* `0`. The first time `testedInt` is an odd number, this is going to hit you, for example, and your loop will never exit.

Take `11`, for example; you'll try the divisors `1`, `2`, and `3`. While `1` is a divisor, `workingInt` will remain `11` and the loop breaks. Next `for` loop, the divisor is `2`, and `workingInt % 2` is not ever going to give you `0`, so the loop will continue forever.

Comment: I want it to be a variable so that the loop keeps on going unless a criteria is met inside the method that stops it.

Comment: @SamHeather: The proper way to do that is to use `while True:` to create an endless loop and then when the condition is met, to use `break` to end the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare global variables `x`, `testedInt` and `workingInt` inside `one_cycle()` in order to access them there:

```
def once_cycle():
    global x
    global testedInt
    global workingInt
```

Answer (score 1):

The `x` from

```
x = 0
```

is not the same as the one from

```
while x==0:
```

See [Using global variables in a function other than the one that created them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them) for how to use a global variable inside a function.

Answer (score 1):

you need to define 3 `globals` in your code of `once_cycle()`:

As variables in functions are defined statically, not when the functions are invoked. So python thinks that the variables `testedInt`,`workingInt` and `x` are considered locals by the function and it Raises error.

```
import math
testedInt = float(raw_input("Enter an int: "))
workingInt = testedInt
x = 0

def once_cycle():
    global x
    global workingInt
    global testedInt
    for dividor in range(1, int(math.floor(math.sqrt(testedInt))+1)):
        while x==0:
            print "Called"
            if (workingInt%dividor == 0):
                workingInt = workingInt/dividor
                x = 1
                if (workingInt > 1):
                    once_cycle()
                return
once_cycle()
```